# How do I programmatically open a specific iOS settings page with Phonegap/Cordova, Ionic, or Angular?

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova

E.g. I want to open programmatically (in my own app) the WiFi or location settings on iOS9?

There is this plugin. But even this doesn't allow me to open a specific settings page on iOS (on Android it works though):
https://github.com/selahssea/Cordova-open-native-settings

Comment: @Paulw11: Since iOS8 it is possible to open the settings of an iOS device. iOS8 was released 2014. The answer/question you referred to was from 2012. So that answer is likely not up-to-date.

Comment: You can open own app's settings but you cannot open system settings such as WiFi or location, so in terms of the question that was asked the duplicate is still accurate